# How to bind a custom authentication parameters C#

Tags: c#, soap, binding

I have an question regarding to HTTP binding. Normally, i can prepare my ClientCrendtialType like

```
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

And the get it ready in the binding. However, the request of third party will require such format in below. Is there a way i can binding my request like that? thank you

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:toa:activity">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:get_route>

<user>
 <now>2016-05-17T13:52:47+0200</now>
 <company>xxxx</company>
 <auth_string>78bec7811af1818ec1bc0031dc7c14f0</auth_string>
</user>

       <date>2016-06-02</date>
         <resource_id>100001361</resource_id>
         <property_filter>status</property_filter>
         <property_filter>duration</property_filter>
         <property_filter>traveling_time</property_filter>
         <property_filter>time_slot</property_filter>
         <property_filter>start_time</property_filter>
         <property_filter>end_time</property_filter>
      </urn:get_route>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found out the SOAP authentication is in the whole SOAP message with MD5 encryption.

Cheers,
Qing